# FileMaker Pro Electronic Signature

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, signature, filemaker, electronic-signature

I have created a document in FileMaker Pro for my company and I need to write a script to where it PDF's and sends an email attachment to the employee in my company to sign. Once the employee signs, I need the document to capture the signature in the FileMaker pro database

> Send Mail [Send via E-mail Client/Send via SMTP Server]; No dialog;
> To: “”; CC: “”; BCC: “”; Subject: “”; Message:
> “”; “”]

Or if possible, can the signatures just be captured directly in the FileMaker Pro database (no iPad, desktop).

Thanks

Comment: You can get your employee signature directly in FileMaker if they use FileMaker Go. If they sign a PDF, there is no easy way you put the signature only back into FileMaker, unless you screenshot it and paste it manually. You can do it if you use Acrobat Pro and ExtendScript and invoke it from FileMaker, but this is quite a project

Comment: Another option is to use signature services such as DocuSign which are easier to integrate or use a JavaScript library in a webviewer

Comment: It isn't very difficult to make a website that will capture a signature and save the signature back to the FileMaker database using the FileMaker Data API. If you don't have the talent in-house then I would suggest searching for a FileMaker developer to make one using one of the many signature capture examples on the web. Send your employee a URL with their unique ID save back to the database with that.